# How to print and remove elements in iterator simultaneously?

Tags: java, iterator, while-loop

I was going through collections in Java and came across some iterator examples. I am giving the code below

```
public class iteratorexample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String removeE="New York";
        List<String> thelist = new ArrayList<String>();

        thelist.add("Dallas");
        thelist.add("Richmond");
        thelist.add("Atlanta");
        thelist.add("New York");
        thelist.add("Birmingham");
        System.out.print(thelist);
        System.out.println();
        Iterator<String> itr= thelist.iterator();
        /*while(itr.hasNext()){

            System.out.print(" " +itr.next()+" ");
        } */
        **while(itr.hasNext()){
            String remo=(String)itr.next();
            if(remo.equals(removeE)){
                itr.remove();

            }

        }**

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("After removing: ");
        System.out.println(thelist);

        }
        }

Above Code give output 
[Dallas, Richmond, Atlanta, New York, Birmingham]

After removing: 
[Dallas, Richmond, Atlanta, Birmingham]
```

Why?

If I use both the while loops the iterator does not remove the element from the list, why? Can you help me out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String removeE="New York";
        List<String> thelist = new ArrayList<String>();

        thelist.add("Dallas");
        thelist.add("Richmond");
        thelist.add("Atlanta");
        thelist.add("New York");
        thelist.add("Birmingham");
        System.out.print(thelist);
        System.out.println();
        Iterator<String> itr= thelist.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){

            System.out.print(" " +itr.next()+" ");
        } 
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            String remo=(String)itr.next();
            if(remo.equals(removeE)){
                itr.remove();

            }

        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("After removing: ");
        System.out.println(thelist);

        }
        }
```

Above code gives output

```
[Dallas, Richmond, Atlanta, New York, Birmingham]
 Dallas  Richmond  Atlanta  New York  Birmingham 
After removing: 
[Dallas, Richmond, Atlanta, New York, Birmingham]
```

Answer (score 4):

> If I use both the while loops the iterator does not remove the element from the list, why?

Because when the first loop is complete, the iterator's `hasNext` is false. So the code never enters the second loop at all.

To loop a second time, you'd have to get a new iterator.

In collections that support it, you could both print and remove in one loop by using the [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) method of the iterator.

```
while(itr.hasNext()){
    String remo=(String)itr.next();
    System.out.print(" " +remo+" ");
    if(remo.equals(removeE)){
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
while(itr.hasNext()){
   System.out.print(" " +itr.next()+" ");
} 
while(itr.hasNext()){
```

so after first while loop your iterator will be completed.